# Google Play Console - run alpha tests after production published

Tags: google-play, google-console-developer

I tried to publish alpha version of my app but I accidentaly promoted it to PROD. I entered Store Presence->Pricing & distribution and unpublished it as soon as possible.
How can I now start alpha/internal tests without going to prod with my previous release?
I've started new Alpha Release and it's in "Full rollout" but no Opt-in URL is available. It still says "An opt-in link will be available here when you publish your app."
Can I start new alpha without going to prod with previous 'buggy' version?

Answer (score 0):

If you've previously not released your app on any track you'll need to start rollout for the alpha track. Then your app will be reviewed and you will get an opt-in URL.

The opt-in link only shows when an app is "Published." Apps in "Draft" or "Pending publication" won't show the opt-in link.

https://support.google.com/googleplay/android-developer/answer/3131213